# How can I parse a "key1:value1, value, key2:value3" string into ArrayLists?

Tags: java

I have a string

```
String line = "abc:xyz uvw, def:ghi, mno:rst, ijk:efg, abc opq";
```

I want to parse this string into two lists:

```
ArrayList<String> tags;
ArrayList<String> values;
```

where the tags are the words before the colon (in my example: `abc`, `def`, `ijk` and `mno`). That is I want

```
tags = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "mno", "ijk");
values = Arrays.asList("xyz uvw", "ghi", "rst", "efg, abc opq");
```

Note that the values can have **spaces** and **commas** in them and are not just one word.

Comment: Split them first by comma separated, then again split with `:`. Maintain two lists and add them to it.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - sorry, can contain commas as well. made the edit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I took the liberty to rewrite your question to make it more generic. If that is not fine for you, you can undo my edit. I hope that helps.

Comment: Your new edit says the values might have commas in them? Is this correct or does this mean that the line you read from file uses commas to separate key-value pairs?

Comment: thanks @MichaWiedenmann

Comment: @milez - the values can have commas in them. Like this: Hi, this is good. My value here is "Hi, this is good" and the tag will be "Like this"

Comment: @Vidya well, that makes things more difficult

Comment: @Vidya Please change the example and include a value with comma. Please also update the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Since your values can contain commas, you need to split when you find a `key`.

A `key` is defined as a word preceding a `:`.

So, your split pattern will be `", (?=[a-zA-z]+:)"`
This checks for a `comma space chars colon` in the specified order, looking ahead the chars and colon.

Checks for a `key`, and splits with lookahead (thus leaving the key intact). This will give you an array of keyValue pairs

Then you can split with `:` to get the keys and values.

```
String str = "Your string";
String[] keyValuePairs = str.split(", (?=[a-zA-z]+:)");
for (String keyValuePair : keyValuePairs) {
    String[] keyvalue = keyValuePair.split(":");
    keysArray.add(keyvalue[0]);
    valuesArray.add(keyvalue[1]);
}
```

Comment: In this approach, I got everything after the ":" as the value, which is not what I needed.

Comment: I edited the answer after testing it out... Did you check it out?

Comment: @Vidya: What happens with the above code and my regex? If it works give answer to Codebender since he bothered to write the code :)

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a regex. I am not sure how to do this in Java but in python that would be:

```
(\w+):([ ,\w]+)(,|$)
```

Tested on [pythex](http://pythex.org/) with input `abc:xy z uvw, def:g,hi, mno:rst`. The result is:

```
Match 1
1.  abc
2.  xy z uvw
3.  ,

Match 2
1.  def
2.  g,hi
3.  ,

Match 3
1.  mno
2.  rst
3.  Empty
```

So for each match you get the key in position 1 and the value in 2. The separator is stored in 3

Comment: can you help me improve this, when you can have `mno:rst` as `Time: 4/30/2015 11:12:09 AM`

Comment: My regex was based on the fact that the key separator does not exist in the data/value field... this complicates a lot! You may need to wrap your data in ```" "``` like CSV does, so you know where a value starts and finishes. However, then you need to escape any quotes inside the value as ```"blah\"blah"```

Answer (score 1):

First obtain your string from the file

```
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>;
String lineThatWasRead = ...
```

Then we split it by commas to obtain the pairs, and for each pari split by `:`

```
List<String> separatedStringList = Arrays.asList(lineThatWasRead.split(","));

for (String str : separatedStringList)
{
    //Since it is possible values also contain commas, we have to check
    //if the current string is a new pair of tag:value or just adding to the previous value

    if (!str.contains(":"))
    {
        if (values.size > 0)
        {
           values.set(values.size() - 1, values.get(values.size()-1) + ", " + str);
           continue; //And go to next str since this one will not have new keys
        }
    }

    String[] keyValArray = str.split(:);
    String key = keyValArray[0];
    String val = keyValArray[1]; 
    tags.add(key);
    values.add(val);   
}
```

Note that you are not forced to use a list but I just like the flexibility they give. Some might argue `String[]` would perform better for the first split by `,`.

Answer (score -1):

You get your line as string.

```
//your code here
String line = //your code here
String[] stuff = line.split(":")// this will split your line by ":" symbol.
stuff[0] //this is your key
stuff[1] //this is your value
```