# how can I split the line on "," even though it has a "," in it

Tags: java

I use the following code to split.

```
List<String> separatedStringList = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
```

Then I parse the string to store into

```
ArrayList<String> tags;
ArrayList<String> values;
```

But when I have a line as follows:

```
abc: def,xyz: pqr, uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

The split on "," causes a problem in the `uvw: abchash<class qwerty, struct Hash<class qwerty>, struct std::equal_to<class qwerty>>::resize` part.

How to solve this?

In continuation to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532189/how-can-i-parse-a-key1value1-value-key2value3-string-into-arraylists)

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You says that you don't want to split the  uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize part ?

Comment: @JFPicard - thats correct. Since the value for the uvw is the entire row until resize, I need that as the value, not just till the first ",".

Comment: Does my answer help with your question? If it does, please mark as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate your string with a stack based algorithm for the generic type constraints  as follows:

**Code**:

```
final String text = "abc: def,xyz: pqr, uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize";

int start = 0;
Stack<Character> generics = new Stack<>();
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case '<':
            generics.push(c);
            break;
        case '>':
            if(generics.isEmpty() || generics.pop() != '<') {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid generic type constraints");
            }
            break;
        case ',':
            if (generics.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(text.substring(start, i));
                start = i + 1; //move window
            }
            break;
    }
}
if (generics.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(text.substring(start));
}
```

**Output**:

```
abc: def
xyz: pqr
 uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

---

**Futher improvements**
Above code can be written as an `Iterable`:

```
public static Iterator<String> iterateValues(String text) {
    return new Iterator<String>() {
        int start = 0;
        Stack<Character> generics = new Stack<>();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return start <= text.length();
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            for (int i = start; i < text.length(); i++) {
                char c = text.charAt(i);
                switch (c) {
                    case '<':
                        generics.push(c);
                        break;
                    case '>':
                        if (generics.isEmpty() || generics.pop() != '<') {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid generic type constraints");
                        }
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        if (generics.isEmpty()) {
                            String result = text.substring(start, i);
                            start = i + 1; //move window
                            return result;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            String result = text.substring(start);
            start = text.length() + 1; //move window
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on ',' and check if the 4th character is ':'. In that case, you take the array, if not, you take the array and the other...

Like this:

```
String[] parts = string.split(",");
int i = 0;
while (i < parts.length) {
  if (parts[i].charAt(4) == ':') {
    //Do something with parts[i] 
    i++;
  }
  else {
    String wantedPart = parts[i];
    i++;
    while(parts[i].charAt(4) != ':' && i < parts.length) {
      wantedPart  = wantedPart + "," + parts[i];
      i++; 
    }
    //Do something with wantedPart 
  }
}
```

That's the general idea. Of course, you would probably want to use a StringBuilder if wantedPart is big.

Comment: I'd assume that the given string is just an example and that there isn't always a `:` in the 4th position. And I'm pretty sure you'd get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with this code - that while loop within a while loop looping over the same thing is not a good design. And you need to insert erroneously removed `,`'s back into the string.

Comment: I've try to make it rapidly, but you're right, my second loop could throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. I corrected it. For the ',', your right also.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right the problem you've got is a malformed input string, where you've got a ',' in the value part of the key/value pairs that you're making.

So you're expecting your input

```
abc: def,xyz: pqr, uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

to parse to

```
abc: def
xyz: pqr
uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

But instead it's parsing to

```
abc: def
xyz: pqr
uvw: abchash<class qwerty
struct Hash<class qwerty>
struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

The solution to this is to fix your input values to either quote round the whole value strings or use some other delimiter to give you some rules.

As far as I can tell you have basically no rules about what you're getting in. It can be a key:value pair or just a value as you have in your example in the other question. In this situation it's impossible to tell the difference between a value containing a comma and the end of one value and the start of another. You said this this string

```
abc:xyz uvw, def:ghi, mno:rst, ijk:efg, abc opq
```

should parse into

```
abc:xyz uvw
def:ghi
mno:rst
ijk:efg
abc opq    <-- no key, just a value
```

which means this

```
abc: def,xyz: pqr, uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

can parse into

```
abc: def
xyz: pqr
uvw: abchash<class qwerty,struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

or equally

```
abc: def
xyz: pqr
uvw: abchash<class qwerty
struct Hash<class qwerty>,struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

or equally

```
abc: def
xyz: pqr
uvw: abchash<class qwerty
struct Hash<class qwerty>
struct std::equal_to<class qwerty> >::resize
```

etc etc

When you have multiple equally valid answers you need to change in input in some way to allow you to narrow down the right one with regex.